# Обработка нажатия в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Добрый день!
Есть список, который отображается в `RecyclerView`. Заполнение элементов списка идет из `item.xml`. `item.xml` содержит `ImageView` and `TextView`. Для `ImageView` по умолчанию поставил значение `invisible`. Для всех элементов списка картинка одна и та же, одинаковая. К примеру, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на один элемент списка, картинка для него становилась видимой. Потом при нажатии на другой элемент - картинка у второго элемента видимая, а у первого становится невидимой.
Я так понимаю, что всю обработку нажатия нужно сделать в адаптере. Но я уже пол дня тыкаю и все никак не выходит. Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением моей проблемы.

Comment: Весь нужный вам код с объяснениями - в ответе-по ссылке на дубль. В вашем случае просто вместо чекнутости чекбокса используйте видимость `ImageView`

Comment: Да, Юрий, это оно самое) Вчера вечером все-таки сам натыкал, как это сделать) Спасибо)